# Fastest way to load data from Google Cloud Storage to Bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, architecture, google-cloud-storage

We need to load data from Google cloud storage to Google Bigquery.
What is the fastest and most cost efficient way?

1. Dataflow -- Bigquery IO write
2. GCStoBQOperator -- Cloud composer

Comment: What is the volume you want to ingest ?

Comment: We're having some 100K+ single-line JSON-files in a bucket, and we're using an external BigQuery-table to get this data into a BigQuery-table for further processing. BR

Answer (score 0):

There is no fastest and cost efficient combination.

1. Load from file, thats free, you can load files that could be 5TB of data. In non compressed mode is the fastest to load expect around 10-120 seconds for load time. [Batch load docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/batch-loading-data).
2. Load via Storage Write API, the default ingestion rate is 3GB per second. You can ingest up to 2TB per month for free, then there are some costs. I have a [slide](https://www.slideshare.net/martonkodok/discover-bigquery-ml-build-your-own-create-model-statement), docs are [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api).
3. all other modes are legacy modes, and either are slow, or library implementations, that wrap some old APIs to do the import.